# Ubuntu Printer Compatability?

Tags: 18.04, printing, laserjet

I am going to be purchasing a new B&W laser printer.  Most of the machines in my home are either Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or iOS.  I'd like this printer to accessible over the wifi from within my house between all these machines.  I went looking for a hardware comparability list so i don't get stuck with a nightmare trying to set up something as simple as a printer and came by this website:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters

Sadly, the content seems a bit dated.  I assume it hasn't been maintained.  Can someone help me find a solid laser B&W printer that plays nice with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list looks like only the ones that they have tested.

I have a HP Laserjet Pro 200 MFP and it works fine on Ubuntu 18.04. It is not on the list you provided.

I had to install the hplib software in order to get it work. Software can be downloaded at https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip

Answer (score 0):

Brother monochrome lasers w/ WiFi in the **HL-** series. I use one and am very happy with it; Mark Fraunfelter at [BoingBoing.net](https://boingboing.net/2019/06/18/cheap-wireless-laser-printer-w.html) uses one.